# "For the course of the next year"?

Tags: grammar

Today, I've started my long-term treatment. The drugs I'll be taking for the next 365 days cannot be combined with alcohol. Therefore, if I want to inform my friend about that, can I phrase my sentences as follows?

> I have to become a compulsory teetotaler for the course of the next year.
>
> I have to become a compulsory teetotaler for the next year.

Answer (score 2):

*The course of* is unnecessary, and to my mind *have to* and *compulsory* are redundant. If what you're trying to do is work in the funny phrase "compulsory teetotaler", I'd do it this way:

> The doctors say I can't drink for a year—I'm a compulsory teetotaler!

Answer (score 1):

If your twin goals here are to be idiomatic and not needlessly wordy, you could say:

> I have to be a teetotaler for the next year.

**Have to be** already expresses the idea that the teetotaling is compulsory.

And if you say "*for* the next year", that nice little preposition **for** already expresses the idea of "the course of".

P.S.  We often use "the course of" with things that gradually come to pass.  ***Over the course of the semester*, we will learn all about Gothic architecture.**